# Pointers on locking all fields in doc files in a folder?

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I've taken some C++ classes and been starting to dabble in C#, and I find myself in the position of needing to lock all the fields in over 15,000 doc files. I'd really like to avoid opening each one and pressing Ctrl+A then Ctrl+F11 in all these files.

I've looked into using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` to open the files to parse through them all and setting `Object.Fields.Locked = True`, but was wondering if anybody knew of a utility, or had any pointers that would be faster than waiting for the Word application to open each file individually to parse through them.

I'm just starting, but all the interop tutorials I find start with creating a document, so I apologize in advance if Word isn't required to open when just manipulating a file. If anybody has any tips for me on this, I'd appreciate them.

Comment: You (or rather, your script) will be instantiating the Word COM object for each one, I'm afraid. You'll just have to leave it running overnight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wanted to mark this question as answered. Ed was right, but I can't mark a comment as an answer. I did just leave my application running overnight, after figuring out some of the particulars for dealing with fields using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.